# Multiple SQL Queries at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a loop in my PHP which i am running an SQL query inside:

```
foreach($records as $result) {
    $sql2.="INSERT into voipwallboard_ast_queue_log (time, callid, queuename, agent, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, queue_id) values ('".$result["time"]."', '".$result["callid"]."', '".$result["queuename"]."', '".$result["agent"]."', '".$result["event"]."', '".$result["arg1"]."', '".$result["arg2"]."', '".$result["arg3"]."', '".$result["queue_id"]."'); ";
}
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
```

then processing the query outside of the loop to do an insert of loads of data rather than processing a query each time inside the loop but it is only inserting one row into my database, what have i done wrong here?

Comment: put the mysql_query inside the loop nad dont concatenate.

Comment: The INSERT bit should be OUTSIDE the loop. Only the VALUES bit of the string needs to be inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Quote: mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)

Also note that the MySQL extension is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `mysqli_multi_query` look sample [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

**Notice**: do not use `mysql_query` it's now deprecated and will removed soon
instead of `mysql_query` you could use [PDO::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or [mysql::query](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) these are new and injection safe

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2 ="INSERT into voipwallboard_ast_queue_log (time, callid, queuename, agent, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, queue_id) values ";

foreach($records as $result) {
$sql2.=" ('".$result["time"]."', '".$result["callid"]."', '".$result["queuename"]."', '".$result["agent"]."', '".$result["event"]."', '".$result["arg1"]."', '".$result["arg2"]."', '".$result["arg3"]."', '".$result["queue_id"]."'), ";
}
rtrim($sql2, ",") // Delete the last comma

$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
```

It is something like:
    INSERT INTO `test`.`tes` (`id` , `date_format`)
    VALUES (NULL , '2014-03-20'), (NULL , '2014-03-22');

If you are using this approach. Only once select query will fire to db, so it will be faster and less load to your db.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2="INSERT into voipwallboard_ast_queue_log (time, callid, queuename,
       agent, event,arg1, arg2, arg3, queue_id) values";

foreach($records as $result) {
    $sql2.="('".$result["time"]."', '".$result["callid"]."', '".
           $result["queuename"]."', '".$result["agent"]."', '".
           $result["event"]."', '".$result["arg1"]."', '".
           $result["arg2"]."', '".$result["arg3"]."', '".$result["queue_id"]."'),; ";
}
rtrim($sql2, ",")
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
```

The part of the query after values should be appended on each run of the loop insetad of the whole insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Just as all have suggested, use `mysqli_multi_query`.

Relevant, but unrelated.  You should store your queries in an array and implode them with a comma, instead of concatenating

```
$sql ="INSERT into voipwallboard_ast_queue_log (time, callid, queuename, agent, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, queue_id) values ";
$inserts = array();

foreach($records as $result)
    $inserts[] ="INSERT into voipwallboard_ast_queue_log (time, callid, queuename, agent, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, queue_id) values ('".$result["time"]."', '".$result["callid"]."', '".$result["queuename"]."', '".$result["agent"]."', '".$result["event"]."', '".$result["arg1"]."', '".$result["arg2"]."', '".$result["arg3"]."', '".$result["queue_id"]."');";

$mQuery = mysqli_multi_query( $sql . implode(',', $inserts) );
```